# Histogram of duplication in n choose k

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Imagine having 17 balls to distribute to 4 people. One algorithm for distributing these balls is to give each ball to one out of the four randomly. This means, in an extreme case, it is possible for 1 person to receive all 17 balls, while the other 3 get none. More likely, however, would be some fairly even distribution, with every person getting at least one ball.

This means it is possible to assign probabilities to the cases in which 0, 1, 2 or 3 people gets no balls.

In general, you have n to distribute among k and probabilities can be given to all k cases in which one or several people get no balls. The number n need not be greater than k.

How does one compute this generally?

Comment: Are the balls identical?

Comment: Yes, sorry. They are all identical. It also does not matter in what order they are given to each person. The only thing which matters is how many balls each person ends up with. In fact, only whether or not he ends up with any balls at all or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) technique can be used here. There are $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ ways to distribute the balls. Suppose that $1\le m\le k$. There are $\binom{k}m$ ways to choose a subset of the $k$ to receive balls, and there are $\binom{n-1}{m-1}$ ways to distribute the balls to that subset in such a way that everyone receives at least one ball. Thus, the probability that exactly $m$ get balls is

$$\frac{\binom{k}m\binom{n-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}}\;.$$

Comment: Great, thanks! Do you know of an easy way to get the probability of having at least $m$ people with balls, other then summing the probability of $m$, $m+1$, ... $k$?

Comment: @LBogaardt: You’re welcome! I don’t immediately see anything much nicer than that, but I’ll give it a little thought.

Answer (score 1):

number of ways of distributing n identical balls into k persons is given by $n+k-1\choose n$.[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

number of ways of distributing n identical balls into m persons so that each of the m person gets at least one ball and the remaining k-m person gets $0$ ball,is given by ${k \choose m}*{n-1\choose m-1}$.

Can you proceed now?

Comment: Yes, we can! Thank you :). Do you know of an easy way to get the probability of having at least $m$ people with balls, other then summing the probability of $m$, $m+1$, ... $k$?